# How to specify to jax-rs UTF-32 input

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I wanna specify to jx-RS to consume UTF-32?

i get exception with letters like ê, é....Ô:

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7b7cef85; line: 1, column: 3219]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidOther(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3473) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidOther(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3480) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._decodeUtf8_2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3254) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2462) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2414) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:285) ~[jackson-core-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need utf-32, your characters can easily be stored in utf-8 as well

Comment: yes but now i have alerdy this exception, i have add
to my pom     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>